# why do i get this [object HTMLInputElement]?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to pre-fill my form when page onload. How do I get the prefilled data when I go back and come in one session time?

```
//inside the validation code
    if (formOkay == false){
        document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "Check, There are some errors !";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "";
        var storage = window.sessionStorage;
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        storage.setItem("First_name",firstName);
    }
    return formOkay;

//inside the function init
//Frist_name = the input name
//firstname = the input id

function init (){
    var formId = document.getElementById("myForm");
    formId.onsubmit = validatingForm;
    //getting the hob reference number using sessionStorage
    document.getElementById("job_number").value = sessionStorage.job_number;

    var storage = window.sessionStorage;
    if (sessionStorage.First_name != "undefined"){
        firstName = storage.getItem("First_name");
        document.getElementById("firstname").value = firstname;
    }else {
        alert("your webpage doesn't support webstorage");
    }

}
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why do i get this [object HTMLInputElement]?

Because JavaScript is **case-sensitive**, so here:

```
document.getElementById("firstname").value = firstname;
```

...you're using the automatic global created for the element by giving it the `id` `"firstname"`. To use your `firstName` variable, be sure to capitalize the `N`.

---

A few other notes:

1. You don't declare your `firstName` variable, so your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables (with `var`, `let`, or `const`).
2. `if (sessionStorage.First_name != "undefined"){` will be true unless someone typed in the name `"undefined"` on a previous visit. To check whether `sessionStorage` has a `First_name` value stored, either compare with `undefined`:

   ```
   if (sessionStorage.First_name !== undefined){
   //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   or use `typeof`:

   ```
   if (typeof sessionStorage.First_name != "undefined"){
   //  ^^^^^^
   ```

   or use `getItem` and check for `null`:

   ```
   if (sessionStorage.getItem("First_name") !== null){
   ```

   More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) and in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).
3. There's no reason to use `storage` (or `window`) in this code:

   ```
   var storage = window.sessionStorage;
   var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
   storage.setItem("First_name",firstName);
   ```

   instead, just:

   ```
   sessionStorage.setItem("First_name", document.getElementById("firstname").value);
   ```

   or use assignment, to mirror the way you're accessing it later:

   ```
   sessionStorage.First_name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
   ```

   (Personally, I prefer `setItem` and `getItem`, but it's a style choice.)
4. Although you *can* use `if (formOkay == false){`, the idiomatic code would be `if (!formOkay){`.